# Multiple dex files define exception

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have got two library projects with practically identical build.gradle files. Both projects have support-library-v4 in dependencies  which declared like this

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.+'
}
```

and uploaded to nexus. The problem is as follows: when I add both (with one library everything is ok) libraries to the main projects the following exception is thrown:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:594)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:552)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:533)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:170)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:439)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:287)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)
```

As far as I understand the command

```
gradlew -q dependencies
```

doesn't shown any redundunt dependencies on support-library-v4

```
releaseApk - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
+--- com.commonsware.cwac:endless:1.2.4
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.+ -> 19.0.1
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.1
+--- com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.3.0
|    \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4
+--- com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.1.1
+--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4
+--- ru.vang:progressswitcher:1.1.2
\--- com.intech:android-commons:1.0.4
```

I'm using Android Studio 0.5.1, gradle-1.11 and the latest sdk. Library are packed in aar and uploaded to Nexus. Dependencies in the main project are

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.commonsware.cwac:endless:1.2.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.+'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile('ru.vang:progressswitcher:1.1.2')
}
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: I just tried a similar experiment with an app including two android-library modules that both depend on appcompat-v7 and didn't see an error. What version of Android Studio/Android Plugin/Gradle are you running? How are you packaging your libraries and depending on them in your project?

Comment: Hello, Scott, I have updated my question. Two libraries depends only on support-v4 (compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.+') and only the main project depends on appcompat-v7.

Comment: Does it work if in your two libraries you include support-v4 via `provided 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.+'`? And then include support-v4 in your main app via `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.+'`?

Comment: No, it doesn't work. It was my first variant when the problem appeared.